# Fazer dump html de uma comunidade privada do Google Plus

Tags: http-request, google-plus

Estou tentando fazer um *request http* de uma página do Google Plus, de um domínio privado. No momento estou utilizando a *lib requests* do Python.

```
import requests
content = requests.get('https://plus.google.com/communities/107246698599792754395')
print content
```

Toda vez dá erro 404, como se a página não existisse. Eu até já estou como membro dessa comunidade. Eu imagino que preciso de algum tipo de autenticação para acesso. Eu já tentei várias outras *libs* e nada. Também tentei via Google API com *OAuth2* e também não obtive sucesso.

Comment: Tentei acessar "https://plus.google.com/communities/107246698599792754395" e de fato ocorre o 404, a url esta correta?

Comment: Esse link é um link privado. Só é visível dentro do domínio da empresa onde trabalho. Minha dúvida é se existe alguma forma de fazer dump de comunidades privadas.